How to change terminal color scheme with .terminal file?
Okay so I tried searching around but couldn't find the answer, probably because I might be dumb. I'm trying to use this terminal theme with vim: https://github.com/sonph/onehalf
To install the vim colors I just placed the colors file in
.vim/colors

How do I make my ubuntu terminal also look like that? I want it to look like this (the light version):
https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf
I don't know what to do with the .terminal file. Where do I place this file:
https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/blob/master/terminal/OneHalfLight.terminal
? Or am I supposed to use this .sh file?
https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/blob/master/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh
Please help. Thank you.
Edit: Forgot to mention
So I cloned the repo into my ~ directory. Then did
source ./onehalf/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh

But my terminal tab is not blue, like in this photo:
https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf
It is gray. :( I am using Ubuntu, the photo looks like it is MacOS? Is that why?

Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/776987/how-to-modify-terminal-in-ubuntu

It says in the README instructions for the gnome-terminal pretty clearly what to do. Is there any particular part of the instructions that are giving you trouble? Did you try those instructions and if so, what was the result? Did it work once and then after a reboot, did it go away? If so, then you may need to add the source commands to like your .bashrc file or some other place to automatically load when you log in to the terminal or open a bash shell.

@mchid Hi oh sorry. So I cloned the repo into my ~ directory. Then did source ./onehalf/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh. But my terminal tab is not blue, like in this photo: https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf. It is gray. :( I am using Ubuntu, the photo looks like it is MacOS? Is that why?

@user20102550 Yeah that looks  like MacOS but I think it can be achieved by editing your existing GTK theme or possibly by installing a different GTK theme. Your GTK theme usually controls the color of the title bars for windows. I think changing the color of your title bar for your GTK theme would be better asked as a separate question, however. The answer would be based on knowing a theme that has that color or editing your existing theme so we would need to know what GTK theme is currently in use.

First of all:
it appears the .terminal files are for OSX so you don't have to worry about those.
Second of all:
the windows in your screenshot appear to be OSX. Window decorations for Ubuntu are typically controlled and set by GTK themes so this is possible but I don't think that would be part of the onehalf theme.
GTK themes set the window decorations, like the borders of the window and the menu bar at the top, and even the window buttons, etc.
There are a few OSX inspired GTK themes available for Ubuntu. Personally, I've never seen one that is blue but the Macos-Sierra GTK theme seems to be pretty popular. It has the round stoplight buttons but the window titlebar is grey and is not blue, however.
Keep in mind that GTK2 themes are no longer supported. Depending on your current GTK theme, you can often simply edit your existing theme to change to the color that you want. I think the details of this would be best served as an answer to a separate question (changing the color of the window titlebar for your GTK theme).
As for installation of the gnome-terminal theme:
Always look for README files when installing stuff from source code or downloaded from github.
The README file for gnome-terminal first says to download or clone the repo. I think this first step is up to you. It appears that you only need the onehalflight.sh file.
Once the file is downloaded into your current working directory, simply source that file (if not in the same directory, then cd into the directory that contains the sh file):
source ./onehalflight.sh

or use the full path to the file. For example, if the file is in your ~/Downloads directory, then you would use:
source ~/Downloads/onehalflight.sh

You may need to close all existing terminal windows and then reopen Gnome Terminal.
